# How to have floating label textbox in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, material-components

Hi I have tried integrating the [MaterialComponentsXamarin](https://github.com/ilap/MaterialComponentsXamarin) in which I will generate textbox dynamically I have applied the following code but I cannot see the floating label when I focus the textbox

```
TextField text = new TextField();
text.Placeholder = "this is floating label";
```

Comment: have you added the TextField to the parent view?

Comment: @Jason I have added the text field & I can able view, but the only thing I cannot see is floating label on focus

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate one of the `TextInputController` objects with a reference to your `TextField`.

For example:

```
var _ = new TextInputControllerOutlined(text);
```

The original swift tutorial shows this in action: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-swift/#2